# Javascript cannot get keys from hashtable

Tags: javascript, hashtable

I have two js files.

File A is to put info from a CSV file into hashtable.Below is the result from file A: *Context info :**{35080014c04=Revised Title, 35080014c2c=Revised Title2, object_id=title}***
File B is to read from this hashtable and turn to an array:

```
var object_id = _theObj.getObjectId() + "";// Return 35080014c04
var mapValues = _context.get("Map");//Return hashtable content from File A
   if (mapValues.containsKey(object_id)) {
        var objVals = mapValues.get(object_id);// return Revised Title
        var enumeration = objVals.keys();//Error
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
```

And the error is: Cannot find function keys in object Revised Title., Source Name: null, Line: 0, Column: 0, Source: null, Exception: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function keys in object Revised Title.

So I wonder If there's any way to get rid of this error?
I'm thinking if it's relate to java version because this script is kinda old and jdk on my machine is 1.8

Comment: Javascript is **not** Java

Comment: Please change the tag to javascript

Comment: Eh, it might be Java and javascript if OP is using Rhino and just completely neglected to tell us that.

Comment: @MrDiggles show me Java where `var` is a valid start of an expression.

Comment: Object.keys is a feature of Javascript 1.8.5. As I'm running these js files via a tool, not relate to any browsers. So I'm wondering how's it involved?